# MySQL two insert statements in one transaction with a dependency

Tags: mysql

Say there are three tables for your bakery business:

```
online_order
invoice
customer_id
```

Your boss calls you and says "I need to order a chocolate cake for all of our clients, invoice them all separately as well". So now you have to do two things:

1. Create an `online_order` entry for each client
2. Then invoice them for that order.

However, each client needs to have their OWN online_order number that they can reference on their invoice.

How can you do this in one transaction? Below is what I have (psuedocode) but I'll show you my output and expected output.

```
BEGIN;
-- First lets create the order
INSERT INTO online_order (online_order_id, date, cake_type, cake_flavor)
VALUES
(AUTO_INCREMENT, NOW(), round, chocolate);

-- Then take that online_order_id and create an invoice out of it for one of our customers
INSERT INTO invoice (date, online_order_id, invoice_amt, customer_id)
SELECT 
  NOW(), 
  LAST_INSERT_ID(), 
  10.00, 
  CUSTOMER_ID
FROM CUSTOMER;

ROLLBACK;
END;
```

My output

```
-- Let's say the next auto-incremented online_order_id is 10011:
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES ("2016-01-01", 10011, 10.00, "1");
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES ("2016-01-01", 10011, 10.00, "2");
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES ("2016-01-01", 10011, 10.00, "3");
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES ("2016-01-01", 10011, 10.00, "4");
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES ("2016-01-01", 10011, 10.00, "5");
```

Desired output (different `online_order_id` for each invoice)

```
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES ("2016-01-01", 10011, 10.00, "1");
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES ("2016-01-01", 10012, 10.00, "2");
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES ("2016-01-01", 10013, 10.00, "3");
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES ("2016-01-01", 10014, 10.00, "4");
INSERT INTO invoice VALUES ("2016-01-01", 10015, 10.00, "5");
```

I need to insert an order, then insert an invoice, then insert an order, then insert an invoice.... for each client. How can I write this in MySQL? Thank you!

Comment: You need a stored procedure so you can write a loop. Or do it in an application language like PHP or Python.

Comment: Open up your customers table in a cursor in a stored proc, loop through the cursor and for each customer do the 2 inserts and commit at the end.

Comment: Your pseudocode only inserts one row? And you don't have a customerid in your orders? Is that really what you want? If you add a customerid to your ordertable (and add a row for each, with `... from customer`), you can just use `INSERT INTO invoice (...) select "2016-01-01", online_order_id, 10.00, customer_id from online_order where online_order_id >= last_insert_id()`. Any real erp system would use a procedure to create invoices, but since your question seems far away from any real world trouble, you could do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table to maintain the `IDs` for different entity and use `SELECT.. FOR UPDATE` to get the atomic values. Table would look like this:

```
Entity | Value
Order  | 1
Blah   | 2
```

You can then use the following block to get the new id:

```
set @id := select value from Ids where Entity = 'Order' FOR UPDATE;

update Ids set value = value + 1 Enity = 'Order';

commit;
```

This would give you the id and increment it by 1. This id then can be used in `invoide` table.

As you will be using `select.. for update`, corresponding row will be locked and no other transaction will be able to read/modify the value, resulting in atomicity.

This approach might prove to be a bottleneck if you have too many insertions executing in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudocode doesn't make much sense - you should only rollback the transaction if it fails. But leaving that aside for now, inserting one row at a time is very innefficient. I would go with something like....

```
INSERT INTO invoice 
    (date, online_order_id, invoice_amt, customer_id, reference)
SELECT 
    NOW(), LAST_INSERT_ID(), 10.00, CUSTOMER_ID, CONNECTION_ID()
FROM CUSTOMER;

INSERT INTO online_order 
(date, cake_type, cake_flavor)
SELECT NOW(), 'round', 'chocolate'
FROM invoice
WHERE reference=CONNECTION_ID();

UPDATE invoice SET reference=NULL
WHERE reference=CONNECTION_ID();
```

The above ensures *most* of the consistency without the use of a transaction at all, although with a procedure you could create a variable and assign its value from uuid() those obviating the need for the final update and keeping an index on reference well balanced.